# Do not show JSON data in columns

Tags: json, sql-server

The software I'm using saves a copy of the data that I think is json in an extra-different table when I do records in the database.

What I want to do is to be able to query the json data contained in the DATASETS column separately.

I'm using SQL 2012 as my server

This is the query I tried so far:

```
SELECT TOP 1 IND, SNAPSHOTDATE, DATASETS, USERNAME, OWNERFORM
FROM TBLSNAPSHOTS
```

CODE RESULT:

````
105 2018-09-14 02:59:34.000 { "Datasets": [{"Name": "TBLSTOKLAR","Lines": [{"IND": "102","STOKNO": "","MALINCINSI": "TITIZ PLASTIK BUYUK KASIK 10 ADET","STOKKODU": "8691262708050","ANABIRIM": "102","BIRIMEX": "102","ALTSEVIYE": "","KRITIKSEVIYE": "","USTSEVIYE": "","DEPOSEVIYESI": "True","URETICI": "","AYLIKVADE": "0","SERINO": "","DEPO": "1","STOKGRUBU": "","GARANTI": "0","PRIM": "0","IPTAL": "False","STOKTIPI": "0","STOKTAKIP": "0","TEMINYERI": "1","RAFOMRU": "0","RESIM": "","KALAN": "0","REZERV": "0","KOD1": "","KOD2": "","KOD3": "","KOD4": "","KOD5": "","KOD6": "","KOD7": "","KOD8": "","KOD9": "","KOD10": "","TAKSITSAYISI": "0","ISTIHBARAT": "","FIYATYOK": "","DELETED": "","ALISFIYATI": "0","ESKIALISFIYATI": "0","SONALISTARIHI": "","SONSATISTARIHI": "","KARTINACILMATARIHI": "14.09.18 ı. 02:57:58","DEVIRIND": "","MALIYET": "1","KDVGRUBU": "1","AKTIF": "False","ISCILIKIND": "0","ISCILIKBIRIMIND": "0","ISCILIKACIKLAMA": "","ISCILIKSTOKKODU": "","ALISFIYATIDEGISMETARIHI": "","STATUS": "1","DALISFIYATI": "","APB": "","OIV": "0","KARORANI": "0","OTV": "0","ISK": "0","STOKGRUPTANIMI": "","ISKSATISFIYATI2": "0","ISKSATISFIYATI3": "0","ALISKDVORANI": "18","ALISISKORANI": "","SIPARISALINMASIN": "False","SIPARISVERILMESIN": "False","P1": "","P2": "","P3": "","SATISKOSULU": "","DEFAULTALISFIYATI": "","DEFAULTALISFIYATIDEGISMESTARIHI": "","KDVGRUBUT": "","HEDEFSATISFIAYTI": "","KURUMISKONTOSU": "","TICARIISKONTO": "","ITSBILDIRIMI": "False","MAXISKORANI": "","IMALATCISATISFIYATI": "","DKUR": "1","ACILSEVK": "False","SOGUKSEVK": "False","ICMIKTAR": "","TICARISEKIL": "","MAXISKTUTAR": "","TAXE": "","KOD11": "","DAPB": "","IKINCIEL": "","ETICARET": "","STOKNEVI": "0","OTVORANSAL": "True","POZ": "","YAZARKASA": "False","KOD12": "","KOD13": "","KOD14": "","KOD15": "","KOD16": "","KOD17": "","KOD18": "","KOD19": "","KOD20": "","KOD21": "","UID": "{0DE71D73-E447-45B0-BF6A-1D312DBAFDD2}"}]}]}    ADMIN   frmEdtStok```
````

Comment: Hi There and welcome to SO, Can you please advise what's not good in the result example you provided and what result you would like to get

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2012 - no, you can't directly query the JSON. In SQL 2016 they added functions to let you do this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

But if you need to stay on 2012 you are limited to String parsing it (**don't do this**), or writing/finding a CLR function which parses it using .Net code and returns the results

If you simply must do it quickly there are some hackey solutions to parse it like so: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/ but don't expect it to work smoothly with complex json